# call() method is not working with functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
function Student(name, age, prof) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.prof = prof;
  this.msg1 = function() {
    console.log(`my name is ${this.name} my age is ${this.age} and i love ${this.prof}`)
  }
  this.msg2 = function() {
    console.log(`my name is ${this.name}my age is ${this.age} and i love ${this.prof}`)
  }
}
//new Student("jack",17,"hacking").msg1() //this works fine
//new Student("rose",21,"hacking").msg2() // this too works fine
Student.call({}, "jack", 17, "hacking")
Student.msg1()
```

Comment: `send me the solution ASAP` you won’t get a answer faster adding such a request.

Answer (score 2):

The first argument of `call` is the replacement value for `this`.

So you are creating a new, empty object and passing it as the `this` value to `Student`. The `Student` function then modifies that object. **Then the object, with the values just added to it, is thrown away** because you do nothing to keep any references to it.

You then try to call `msg1()` on the `Student` function object, but it doesn't exist there because you never assign a value to the `msg1` property of **that** object.

---

Now you **could** pass `Student` itself as the this value.

```
Student.call(Student, "jack", 17, "hacking")
```

and then the next line of your code would work.

I don't recommend that you do though.

---

Or you could create an object, keep a reference to it, and then use that.

```
const jack = {};
Student.call(jack, "jack", 17, "hacking")
jack.msg1();
```

Which is less horrible, but still not great.

---

`call` is useful when you need to borrow a method from an object, such as when you have an array-like object and you want to use a real array method on it.

**`Student` is designed to work as a constructor function. You should use it as one.**

```
const jack = new Student("jack",17,"hacking");
jack.msg1();
```

If you wanted to redesign it to modify an existing object, then it would be better to write it as a regular function which expected the object you wanted to modify as an argument.

Comment: will you send me the correct code with assigned value ?

Comment: @programmercore — Umm. See the code that is already in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that I am repeating what Quentin said, but, I have a straight forward answer.

```
function Student(name, age, prof) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.prof = prof;
  this.msg1 = function() {
    console.log(`my name is ${this.name} my age is ${this.age} and i love ${this.prof}`)
  }
  this.msg2 = function() {
    console.log(`my name is ${this.name}my age is ${this.age} and i love ${this.prof}`)
  }
}

Student.call({}, "jack", 17, "hacking");
```

When you use `.call` function, the first parameter to it becomes `this` inside the function. So, when you say `.call({}, ...)`, the `{}` becomes the `this` inside the function. The same will be populated with `name, age, prof, msg1, msg2` properties. So, it worked as it is expected to.

The problem is with your understanding. You thought that, doing `Student.call({}, ...)` will add the `name, age, prof, msg1, msg2` properties in `Student`. As I mentioned above, those properties are populated in the `{}` that you passed as the first parameter.

So, if you want to access the properties created inside the `Student` constructor, then create a reference to the first parameter & pass that to the `.call` function. Then, you can access those properties, through the reference, as follows:

```
const student = {};
Student.call(student, "jack", 17, "hacking");

student.name; // jack
student.msg1() // my name is jack my age is 17 and i love hacking
```

But, as Quentin advised, do not use this pattern to create object instances. Use the constructor instead.

Comment: very muck thanks sir